# Docker stack deploy on GCP cannot access the webpage

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to use docker swarm and docker stack to deploy my docker-compose file and after I've deployed my stack successfully, I can't access the web page. It just says the response time is too long with the error message "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" I have also opened the TCP and UDP ports 7946, and 4789 as well. Does anyone know what went wrong?

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:latest
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbRoot
            MYSQL_DATABASE: cloud
            MYSQL_USER: php
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: php
        networks:
            - mynet
    myphp:
        image: php:7.4-apache
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.role == manager
        networks:
            - mynet
    mynginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        depends_on:
            - myphp
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 2
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.role == manager
        networks:
            - mynet
    visualizer:
            image: dockersamples/visualizer:latest
            ports:
              - "8080:80"
            volumes:
              - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
            deploy:
              placement:
                constraints: [node.role ==  manager]
    phpMyAdmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
        ports:
            - "8082:80"
        networks:
            - mynet
volumes:
    src:
networks:
    mynet:
        driver: overlay
```

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                             PORTS
9ef6kj1wois8        test_mysql          replicated          1/1                 mariadb:latest                    
jjcmp9lrr35f        test_mynginx        replicated          2/2                 nginx:latest                      *:80->80/tcp
oogi9emcjo0j        test_myphp          replicated          1/1                 php:7.4-apache                    *:9000->9000/tcp
re8wnkvcxgo2        test_visualizer     replicated          0/1                 dockersamples/visualizer:latest   *:8080->80/tcp
y9i19mxjp69q        test_phpMyAdmin     replicated          1/1                 phpmyadmin:latest                 *:8082->80/tcp
```

```
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                             NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR               PORTS
c7b6bv6qgqbn        test_visualizer.1   dockersamples/visualizer:latest   manager             Running             Starting 11 seconds ago                       
xu9cvjjp4xqt        test_mynginx.1      nginx:latest                      manager             Running             Running 10 seconds ago                        
klf8nimlljbp        test_myphp.1        php:7.4-apache                    manager             Running             Running 10 seconds ago                        
0epkhwsmub8c        test_mysql.1        mariadb:latest                    w1                  Running             Running 14 seconds ago                        
zlluox3ga6fw        test_phpMyAdmin.1   phpmyadmin:latest                 manager             Running             Running 12 seconds ago                        
knmvjwmcslsj        test_mynginx.2      nginx:latest                      manager             Running             Running 10 seconds ago
```

Comment: you need to update the firewall rules in GPC to allow TCP inbound traffic on port 80 and 443